# Change published date to 12 hour time

Tags: 6

Right now my nodes say published by "author name 19:02". How can I change it to display 12 hour time 7:02?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It uses the default date format of the site, which is medium. You can configure that at admin/settings/date-time and choose a format which uses am/pm.

You can also implement `hook_preprocess_node()` in your theme or module and then override the 'submitted' variable set by [template_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_node/6). That allows you to use a different date format just there.

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal there are specific theming functions to customize this:

This is the default (for nodes):

```
function theme_node_submitted($node) {
  return t('Submitted by !username on @datetime',
    array(
      '!username' => theme('username', $node),
      '@datetime' => format_date($node->created),
    ));
}
```

This is the default for comments:

```
function theme_comment_submitted($comment) {
  return t('Submitted by !username on @datetime.',
    array(
      '!username' => theme('username', $comment),
      '@datetime' => format_date($comment->timestamp)
    ));
}
```

To override them, add these functions in your template.tpl.php of your theme, and change the name to `MYTHEME_node_submitted`. And now you can customize it:

Drupal 6 uses by default the format 'D, m/d/Y - H:i' , to understand the meaning of these letters, [see full PHP doc here](http://php.net/date)

To display in 12 hour format, replace H by h like this:

```
format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'D, m/d/Y - h:i');
```

[API reference about format_date()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/format_date/6)